# Send Active Campaign event data to Google Analytics or Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, css

my automation in Active Campaign contains two steps that belong to Google Analytics Ecommerce Enhance Checkout Behaviour Analysis. How can I transfer data that the email was open and the link inside that email was clicked to Google Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

You can use measurement protocol https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/ to collect data about email openings and UTM parameters to track link clicks.